# .NET EF HttpRequestException Error while copying content to a stream, using awaits

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I have the following code which throws an exception on the last line. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, EF .NET MVC. The method is an `async Task<ActionResult>` and does not use "using" blocks.

I've been rattling my head for answers, does anyone have a solution ?

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"accountId", directDebit.Account.Id},
    {"ddInfoId", directDebit.Id},
    {"instructionType", type}
};

HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
var uri = new Uri(_apiBaseUrl + "/Correspondence/GenerateDirectDebitCorrespondence");
var authToken = await _apiCommunicator.GetToken();
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authToken);

var response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, data);
```

Update: Some more information, the API call is

```
File = new File
{
    CreatedByUserId = _context.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == "System").Id,
    CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
}

return File
```

Comment: The error is coming form your API here it seems, you need to debug that.

Comment: Thanks David, I've been looking into the API and I think that the problem is that I'm passing back a File (see update) would it be better to pass the file as a string?

Comment: What is exception message that you are getting?